# On a Codeforces combinatorics problem, from $O(m^2n)$ to $O(n \times \min(m, n))$? [Codeton 5 Problem G]

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

**Problem link**: https://codeforces.com/contest/1842/problem/G

**Brief explaination**:

Given a positive integer array $a$ ($1$-indexed) of length $n$ ($1 \leq n \leq 5000$) and a positive integer $v$, perform the following operation $m$ ($1 \leq m \leq 10^9$) times:

Operation: Choose an index $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) **uniformly** at random, then for all $i \leq j \leq n$, set $a_j := a_j + v$, i.e., increase $a_j$ by $v$.

Find the expectation value of $\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i]$.

**My idea**:

The $O(m^2n)$ algorithm is quite simple:

Let $dp[i (1 \leq i \leq n)][j (1 \leq j \leq m)]$ be the expectation when considering index $i$ and there are $j$ operations used in the first $i$ indices. Therefore, $a_i$ has to become $a_i + jv$, as each operations on indices before $i$ (before means $\leq$) increases $a_i$ by $v$. Therefore, we iterate over the number of operations (we denote it $c$ in the following equation) that are exactly on $v$, formally:

$dp[i][j] = \sum\limits_{c = 0}^{j}(a_i + jv)\binom{j}{c}dp[i-1][j-c]$.

This is obviously $O(m^2n)$ as there are $O(mn)$ states and each transition takes $O(m)$ time. However, $O(m^2n)$ is too slow as $m$ could be as large as $10^9$. The standard solution is $O(n \times \min(m, n))$ but I don't know how to achieve that. I couldn't even understand the [editorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/117606), so would you please help me understand the editorial? You are warmly welcome if your idea is different from the editorial, even if the idea is incomplete.

Comment: Just curious... Did you try posting it on Computer Science site?

Comment: No lady/bro, It seems that MSE's population is much larger than the CSE, so I posted it here. I believe algorithm is a part of math. Given an identity, some deformation might make it much faster to compute.

Comment: Example $1$: $n=m=2$, $v=5$, $a=[2, 2]$. Then:  $a_1 = 2,\,a_2 = 12$ with $\frac{1}{4}$ possibility, $a_1 = a_2 = 12$ with $\frac{1}{4}$ possibility, $a_1 = 7,\,a_2 = 12$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ possibility. The answer is $\frac{1}{4}(2 \times 12+12 \times12)+\frac{1}{2}(7 \times 12)=84$.

Comment: I didn't judge you, lady-bro, I just asked have you tried? I do know that math wizzards and better at this than computer science wizzards, but maybe at this particular problem they beat us. Have luck.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to cross-post, I'd say you are more likely to get a response there.

Comment: Did you understand the "2 basic properties of expected value" in the tutorial? If no, you should go on figure that out. If yes, think about how that simplifies the problem at the high level, before you start doing any computations.

Comment: Check my blog for detail: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/117640

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my blog for detail: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/117640 for an answer.

Explanation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D6ESAuTFvnhAe-lIIzmAqtC3phaTRm06/view?usp=sharing

Code: https://codeforces.com/contest/1842/submission/211089837